# Kivy md tabs: how to add tooltips

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to develop an interface in Python / Kivy Md. The container Box Layout should include three widgets: tabs, a label and a button. I would like to add a tooltip for each tab. The tooltip should be displayed when the mouse moves on the tab. I added the tooltip in my code, but this is displayed only when the mouse is moved outside the corresponding tab, such as on the label in the middle of the screen. Here my code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons
from kivymd.uix.tooltip import MDTooltip
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 10, 0, 10, 10
        
    MDTabs:
        id: tabs
        on_tab_switch: app.on_tab_switch(*args)
        
    MDLabel:
        text: app.myLabel
        pos_hint: {"x":0.5}
        
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'CONFIGURE'
        size_hint_x: 1
        pos_hint: {"center_y":0.5}
'''


class Tab(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase, MDTooltip):
    '''Class implementing content for a tab.'''


class MainApp(MDApp):
    icons = ["clock", "video-3d", "speedometer"]
    icons_tooltips = ["TIMESTAMP", "ORIENTATION", "HIGH RATE"]
    myLabel = StringProperty()

    def build(self):
        self.title = 'XSENS MTi-7 OUTPUT CONFIGURATION'
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for icon in range(len(self.icons)):
            self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget(Tab(icon = self.icons[icon], tooltip_text = self.icons_tooltips[icon]))

    def on_tab_switch(
        self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text
    ):
        '''
        Called when switching tabs.

        :type instance_tabs: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabs object>;
        :param instance_tab: <__main__.Tab object>;
        :param instance_tab_label: <kivymd.uix.tab.MDTabsLabel object>;
        :param tab_text: text or name icon of tab;
        '''
        count_icon = instance_tab.icon
        self.myLabel = count_icon
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    MainApp().run()
```

Any suggestion to make the tooltip appear when the mouse is on the tab?

Answer (score 0):

According to the KivyMD docs, MDTooltip only works correctly with button and label classes.
https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/tooltip/index.html

You could also ask on the KivyMD Discord server, they have helped me out a lot: https://discord.gg/wu3qBST

Comment: Thank you anyway! May I kindly ask if you know how to use an external image (such as a .png) as an icon in MD Tabs? There are lots of default icons, but sometimes they are not enough!

Comment: I am not sure how do that. You might be able to use a canvas to display the image in the tab.  I would ask on the kivy discord server as the developers hang out there and are very helpful. https://chat.kivy.org